# UpdatePanel does not fire on first click of link button

Tags: ajax, updatepanel, scriptmanager

I have an update panel on an .aspx page. Within this aspx page I have a few ascx controls. One of the controls has my link button. When that button is pressed I'd expect to get the results I intend to get, but I expect to not see a page flicker or see the page postback. It does both. After I change some search information and click the link button again the page does an async postback (which is what I expected on the first click). After running this sequence through fiddler I see that the first time I click the button I am missing some information that is included in all subsequent requests.

ctl00$ScriptManager1=ctl00$cplContents$updatePanelOrderSearch|ctl00$cplContents$ucOrderSearchControl$btnRange&**EVENTTARGET=ctl00%24cplContents%24ucOrderSearchControl%24btnRange&**.....

Above is what I get on clicks 2, 3, etc.. This is not in the request when I click on the link button the very first time. Im wondering if this is why I am get a full, non async postback the first time.

Any help would be appreciated. My update panel code is below.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updatePanelOrderSearch" runat="server" UpdateMode="Always" ChildrenAsTriggers="true">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <uc:control1 "this control has the link button" />
        <hr />
        <div id="SearchResults">
            <div id="SearchResultsMessage">
                <asp:Literal ID="lblMessage" Text="No orders found" Visible="false" runat="server" />
            </div>
            <uc:contorl 2 />
        </div>
        <uc: control3 />
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

this was an issue from months ago and we wound up not using this solution

Comment: Please explain your answer